# +/- after a job in the background is done

Tags: shell, background-process, job-control

Run a job in the background

```
$ command &
```

When it's done, the terminal prints

```
[n]+    command
```

or

```
[n]-    command
```

So sometimes it's a plus and other times it's a minus following `[n]`.

What does plus/minus mean?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They are to distinguish between current and previous job; the last job and the second last job for more than two jobs, with `+` for the last and `-` for the second last one.

From `man bash`:

> The previous job may be referenced using `%-`.  If there is only a
>   single job, `%+` and `%-` can both be used to refer to that job.  In
>   output pertaining to jobs (e.g., the output of the jobs command), the
>   current job is always flagged with a `+`, and the previous job with a 
>   `-`.

#### Example:

```
$ sleep 5 &
[1] 21795

$ sleep 5 &
[2] 21796

$ sleep 5 &
[3] 21797

$ sleep 5 &
[4] 21798

$ jobs
[1]   Running                 sleep 5 &
[2]   Running                 sleep 5 &
[3]-  Running                 sleep 5 &
[4]+  Running                 sleep 5 &

$ 
[1]   Done                    sleep 5
[2]   Done                    sleep 5
[3]-  Done                    sleep 5
[4]+  Done                    sleep 5
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you are referring to when you check jobs via `$jobs`. However, as you probably know already, `n` denotes the job #. The `[n] +` denotes the final job that was called.
`[n] -` denotes the second to last job that is called.

**For example:**

```
chris@chris-VirtualBox:~$ sleep 30 &
[1] 904
chris@chris-VirtualBox:~$ sleep 50 &
[2] 972
chris@chris-VirtualBox:~$ jobs
[1]-  Running                 sleep 30 &
[2]+  Running                 sleep 50 &
```

That is why, in this case, our `sleep 50 &` is last: `[2]+` and `sleep 30 &` is second to last: `[1]-`

Comment: Your description of the situation is unclear and the system does not predict which job will end first.

Comment: I see what you mean, I will emphasize the main point